# Magento Rest API - white space sku issue

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

**Issue**

Unable to get update price via REST API due to white space in the sku

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Create a product with SKU containing white space, eg. 'BAH SB'
2. Query Magento instance via REST API /rest/V1/products/BAH SB
3. Observe response

**I tried URL Encoding**:

> /rest/V1/products/BAH%20SB
>
> /rest/V1/products/BAH+SB

but didn't work.

Any Help?

Comment: Try like that "/rest/V1/products/BAH SB"

Comment: @JayParmar Thank you for your comment. Syntactically, a URI must not contain a literal space and it must be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to the endpoint documentation (https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.7-admin/tag/products), you are supposed to make a POST call to the endpoint URL `/rest/default/V1/products` and the payload can look something like this:

```json
{
 "product": {
     "sku": "BAH SB",
     "price": 999
 }
}
```

There is no query parameter that you need to add to the endpoint URL.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tested but unfortunately it not working in the case of white space in a SKU.

Comment: that's really weird, i just tested this before answering and it was working properly. but tell me, what errors do you get in the response?